# Javascript "Tooltip" with continuously changing content

Tags: javascript, tooltip

I have a canvas element and I want to show a tooltip following the mouse pointer with the text in the tooltip continuously changing depending on what is currently under the pointer.

I have found [qtip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/) but it looks like it is geared more towards a declarative approach where you don't have the text in your tooltip continuously changing. Also it looks a bit of an overkill for a simple text tooltip. I may be wrong though.

So how do I show a tooltip (with the ability to continuously change its contents and coordinates) with javascript (any libraries permitted)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up modifying the [hoverbox](http://koteako.com/hoverbox/) plugin slightly to allow for the text to be updated while mouseover'ing the element so that I can set the title attribute in my other mouseover handler to update the hoverbox:

```
/*
 * jQuery Hoverbox 1.0
 * http://koteako.com/hoverbox/
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2009 Eugeniy Kalinin
 * Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses.
 * http://koteako.com/hoverbox/license/
 */
/*
*  Slightly modfied to allow for updating the text
*  of the hoverbox while mouseover the element
*/
jQuery.fn.hoverbox = function(options) {
    var settings = jQuery.extend({
        id: 'tooltip',
        top: 0,
        left: 15
    }, options);

    var handle;
    var that;

    function tooltip(event) {
        if ( ! handle) {
            // Create an empty div to hold the tooltip
            handle = $('<div style="position:absolute;background:white;border:black;" id="'+settings.id+'"></div>').appendTo(document.body).hide();
        }

        if (event) {
            //update the text
            that.t = that.title;
            that.title = '';
            handle.html(that.t);

            // Make the tooltip follow a cursor
            handle.css({
                top: (event.pageY - settings.top) + "px",
                left: (event.pageX + settings.left) + "px"
            });
        }
        return handle;
    }

    this.each(function() {
        $(this).hover(
            function(e) {
                that = this;
                tooltip(e).fadeIn('fast');
            },
            function() {
                if (this.t) {
                    this.title = this.t;
                    tooltip().hide();
                }
            }
        );
        $(this).mousemove(tooltip);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 2):

theres a plugin http://koteako.com/hoverbox/

folowes your mouse youst change its content on mousemove

Comment: This sets the text on mouseover and you cannot change it continuously.